# Auto-adjust column width to fit the content in panda generated Excel files

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I am using [`pandas.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) to generate `xlsx` files.

On my Win10 `openpyxl` is used by default because `xlsxwriter` is not installed. My question goes to both options.

The columns of resulting `xlsx` files are to small for the content. I have to adjust them via Excel.

This is how a generated sheet looks like

[image]

And this is how it looks like after auto-adjust the width in Excel itself.

[image]

I want that pandas/openpyxl/xlsxwriter does this auto-adjusting by itself. Is there an option or a way for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reliable way I know to do this is to use [`.autofit()`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=autofit#xlwings.Sheet.autofit) in xlwings:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

filename = r"test.xlsx"
df = pd._testing.makeDataFrame()
df.to_excel(filename)

with xw.App(visible=False):
    wb = xw.Book(filename)
    for ws in wb.sheets:
        ws.autofit(axis="columns")
    wb.save(filename)
    wb.close()
```

Be aware that using xlwings requires Microsoft Excel to be installed.

Comment: Why is xlwings trying to access "System Events" in Mac OS?

Comment: Sorry, I am not a mac user. Does this help? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/416095